# Using IdentityServer3 with a standalone EXE (without using 'redirect_uri'?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, exe, identityserver3

I have a web site I'm developing that uses IdentityServer3 to authentication with, and it also returns an access token to enable access to my APIs.  All works well.  I'm now rewriting the web site into a standalone windows EXE.  The EXE is written in React and Electron to make it a standalone application.  My problem is: I call the 'authorize' endpoint to my identityserver3 server, but I do not know what to put in for the 'redirect_uri' required by identityserver3?  Since my EXE is standalone it has no uri address?

Is there a way to use IdentityServer3 as an API, where I can send the 'authorize' url to IdentityServer3, and have it return the access token as a response (to the API call?)

Comment: You want to use the [Token](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/token.html) endpoint instead, using e.g. the Client Credentials flow.

Comment: Is there a javascript or node component that lets you do Client Credentials flow (in JS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as Kirk Larkin says - use the Client Credentials flow.

The following code is in .NET:

```
 var client = new TokenClient(
            BaseAddress + "/connect/token",
            "clientId",
            "clientSecret");

var result = client.RequestClientCredentialsAsync(scope: "my.api").Result;

var accessToken = result.AccessToken;
```

Where BaseAddress is your IDS address.

Of course you will have to register your client in the IDS clients list with the appropriate flow (Client Credentials), and the scope is just optional, but I guess you will need one.

Then accessing a protected API is fairly easy:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
var result = client.GetStringAsync("https://protectedapiaddress").Result;
```

**EDIT**: For JavaScript approach:

[This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-oauth2) and [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/client-oauth2) look like a working solution, but I've tried neither of them

Comment: That's in the right direction!  Would you know of a way to do this in JavaScript? The 'RequestClientCredentialsAsync' part I mean.

Comment: @MichaelBHildebrand - I edited the answer. Hope that it helps

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful!